# java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn

Tags: clojure

I am just trying to set the value of the cookie named test.

```
example: http://www.luminusweb.net/docs/sessions_cookies.md
```

My code:

```
    (GET "/new-location" req (new-location req)
     (-> "cookie set" response (update-in [:cookies "test" :value] "Alice")))
```

Error:

```
java.lang.String cannot be cast to clojure.lang.IFn
```

In case you want to see new-location function:

```
(defn new-location [resp]
 (render "{{resp}}" {:resp resp}))
```

Resp Output:

```
{:ssl-client-cert nil, :cookies {"test" {:value "5Zn5Z6shY7vJFH3dYyhmDzfB/MmLkZVShKxxrNXop7QgubGBLBGQMzsdPX3c9kJkc/H3oFns/Y3+yU5RNXmBCp+Hs5ha0mEMhiRcGw04Z4w=--BZCShBKs13BCNkVGtyKAtuOMqPCH+sFl3t39qnM6Eks="}}, :remote-addr "127.0.0.1", :params {}, :flash nil, :handler-type :undertow, :route-params {}, :headers {"host" "localhost:3000", "user-agent" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/45.0.2454.15 Safari/537.36", "cookie" "test=5Zn5Z6shY7vJFH3dYyhmDzfB%2FMmLkZVShKxxrNXop7QgubGBLBGQMzsdPX3c9kJkc%2FH3oFns%2FY3%2ByU5RNXmBCp%2BHs5ha0mEMhiRcGw04Z4w%3D--BZCShBKs13BCNkVGtyKAtuOMqPCH%2BsFl3t39qnM6Eks%3D", "connection" "keep-alive", "upgrade-insecure-requests" "1", "accept" "text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8", "accept-language" "en-GB,en-US;q=0.8,en;q=0.6", "accept-encoding" "gzip, deflate, sdch", "dnt" "1", "cache-control" "max-age=0"}, :server-port 3000, :content-length -1, :form-params {}, :compojure/route [:get "/new-location"], :session/key "5Zn5Z6shY7vJFH3dYyhmDzfB/MmLkZVShKxxrNXop7QgubGBLBGQMzsdPX3c9kJkc/H3oFns/Y3+yU5RNXmBCp+Hs5ha0mEMhiRcGw04Z4w=--BZCShBKs13BCNkVGtyKAtuOMqPCH+sFl3t39qnM6Eks=", :server-exchange #object[io.undertow.server.HttpServerExchange 0x2035c15c "HttpServerExchange{ GET /new-location}"], :query-params {}, :content-type nil, :path-info "/new-location", :character-encoding nil, :context "", :uri "/new-location", :server-name "localhost", :query-string "", :body #object[io.undertow.io.UndertowInputStream 0x2ef23b2a "io.undertow.io.UndertowInputStream@2ef23b2a"], :multipart-params {}, :scheme :http, :request-method :get, :session {:ring.middleware.session-timeout/idle-timeout 1438182648}}
```

Comment: `(macroexpand '(-> "cookie set" response (update-in [:cookies "test" :value] "Alice")))` gives
`(update-in (response "cookie set") [:cookies "test" :value] "Alice")` - are you sure thats what should happen ?

Comment: I am just using the code in the documentation link I posted, are you saying that it's wrong?

Comment: What's `new-location`? I would say it's a string, and the error occurs when trying to evaluate `(new-location req)`

Comment: by the way, the form using the threading macro `->` which you took from the luminus page seems to be fine. `response` is ring.util.response/response which returns a map with :status, :headers and :body, so it's a perfect candidate for `update-in`. For more info on response, see https://github.com/ring-clojure/ring/wiki/Creating-responses

Comment: hummm, @bsvingen is right in his answer: the `update-in` form is wrong, it takes a function. An alternative to use `constantly` is to use `assoc-in`:  `(-> "cookie set" response (assoc-in [:cookies "test" :value] "Alice")))`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[update-in](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure.core/update-in) takes a function for providing the new value, not the new value - do

```
(update-in [:cookies "test" :value] (constantly "Alice"))
```

instead.

Comment: Do you need to make that a anon fn `#(constantly "Alice")`?

Comment: No. `update-in` takes a function to provide the new value, `(constantly "Alice")` provides a function that returns the value "Alice".